# Creating a Map from an extremely nested array using java streams

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-stream

I've got this JSON array that I'm attempting to stream through and can't figure things out. **I need to create a map that stores the conference rank of the team as the key and the team name as the value, coming from the `List<Records>` records list.** I'm not great at streams or `for` loops so I was hoping someone could help.

JSON

```
Records{teamRecordsList=[TeamRecords{conferenceRank='1', team=Team{name='Washington Capitals'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='3', team=Team{name='Pittsburgh Penguins'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='5', team=Team{name='New York Islanders'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='6', team=Team{name='Columbus Blue Jackets'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='9', team=Team{name='Carolina Hurricanes'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='10', team=Team{name='Philadelphia Flyers'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='12', team=Team{name='New York Rangers'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='15', team=Team{name='New Jersey Devils'}}]}Records{teamRecordsList=[TeamRecords{conferenceRank='2', team=Team{name='Boston Bruins'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='4', team=Team{name='Tampa Bay Lightning'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='7', team=Team{name='Florida Panthers'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='8', team=Team{name='Toronto Maple Leafs'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='11', team=Team{name='Montréal Canadiens'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='13', team=Team{name='Buffalo Sabres'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='14', team=Team{name='Ottawa Senators'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='16', team=Team{name='Detroit Red Wings'}}]}Records{teamRecordsList=[TeamRecords{conferenceRank='1', team=Team{name='St. Louis Blues'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='2', team=Team{name='Colorado Avalanche'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='4', team=Team{name='Dallas Stars'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='9', team=Team{name='Nashville Predators'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='10', team=Team{name='Chicago Blackhawks'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='11', team=Team{name='Winnipeg Jets'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='12', team=Team{name='Minnesota Wild'}}]}Records{teamRecordsList=[TeamRecords{conferenceRank='3', team=Team{name='Vancouver Canucks'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='5', team=Team{name='Calgary Flames'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='6', team=Team{name='Vegas Golden Knights'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='7', team=Team{name='Edmonton Oilers'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='8', team=Team{name='Arizona Coyotes'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='13', team=Team{name='San Jose Sharks'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='14', team=Team{name='Anaheim Ducks'}}, TeamRecords{conferenceRank='15', team=Team{name='Los Angeles Kings'}}]}
```

Java code

```java
@Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            Standings standings = restTemplate.getForObject(
                    "https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/standings", Standings.class);
            List<Records> records = standings.getRecords();
            records.stream()
                    .forEach(System.out::print);
        };
```

Here you can see the current code I've reverted to that prints the above JSON array that I included.

Comment: you can refer to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to see if your JSON is valid or not. The JSON you provided is not valid as it stands now.

Comment: You are using toString() method in hidden way in this row: records.stream()
                    .forEach(System.out::print);
This is not JSON string.